# Runtime binding change + unexpected event firing issue WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I change binding at runtime with datatriggers in XAML like this:

```
<ToggleButton Checked="MinSyncX_OnChecked" Unchecked="MinSyncX_OnUnchecked" TargetUpdated="FrameworkElement_OnTargetUpdated"
        Tag="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ToolTip="{Binding Source={StaticResource CameraLocalization}, Path=ToolTips.SyncX, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton" BasedOn="{StaticResource CameraSyncCommonStyle}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.SelectedLimitation.W, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.IsMinTripleEnabled.X, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.IsMinTripleChecked.X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.SelectedLimitation.W, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.IsMaxTripleEnabled.X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.IsMaxTripleChecked.X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.SelectedLimitation.W, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.IsBothTripleEnabled.X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="IsChecked" Value="{Binding Path=CameraViewDirection.Limitations.UI.IsBothTripleChecked.X, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
    <ToggleButton.Content>
        <Image Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource CameraIcons}, Path=XAxis, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Image>
    </ToggleButton.Content>
</ToggleButton>
```

Everything seems fine - binding really changes, but I have one issue which I don`t know how to solve:

- When binding changed, `MinSyncX_OnUnchecked` event firing even if binded value is true which means that Toggle button must stays checked.
- Firing of this event during binding  switching braked my code, so I wish to now how to suppress this event during binding change if `IsChecked` property must be set to true.

A little tricky, but I hope you will understand my problem.

**Edit**

One thing I noticed that unchecked event ALWAYS fired if data trigger value switched to the first in list. Even it has a value=1 or value=2. 
Does this by design or it can be fixed somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise that I have twoway binding, so, when binding changed, my binded property receive value from button first (thats the reason why unchecked event firing). The solution I found is: lock logic of unchecked event by some bool value and switch that value back when binding changed (selection changed event on combobx in my case)